# Runtime Error in VBA Project

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I keep getting an error whenever I run this code. The error is a 1004 runtime error. Please help me figure out where my code went wrong. I am completely new to VBA but I do know how to use Python and C.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Experiment()

    Dim m1 As Worksheet
    Set m1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim col As Integer
    Dim row As Integer

    Dim initial As Double

    Dim s1 As Double
    Dim s1_pos As Integer
    Dim s2 As Double
    Dim s2_pos As Integer

    Dim min As Double
    Dim candidate As Double
    Dim temp_swap As Double

    Dim r As Integer

    col = 2
    'For col = 2 To 18 Step 3
    For row = 5 To 47 Step 2
        initial = m1.Cells(row, col).Value
        s1 = m1.Cells(row + 1, col).Value
        s1_pos = row + 1
        min = Abs(36 - (initial + s1))
        r = row + 1

        Do While r < 49
            s2 = m1.Cells(r, col).Value
            candidate = Abs(36 - (initial + s2))
            If candidate < min Then
                min = candidate
                s2_pos = r
            End If
            r = r + 1
        Loop

        temp_swap = s1
        m1.Cells(s1_pos, col).Value = s2
        m1.Cells(s2_pos, col).Value = temp_swap

    Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Please specify @ which line error is thrown? Would be great if you can share excel sheet sheet shot as well

Comment: @Kurst what are you trying to achieve ? because your `While` loop seems to be not ideal, are you looking for a minimum value that depends on a dynamic range ? In that case you can use `Match` with `Min`

Comment: @Siva   m1.Cells(s2_pos, col).Value = temp_swap, sorry the snippet tool not working :'(

Comment: @ShaiRado, I have a list of capacitors that should be more or less equal to 18. Essentially, I am adding up different pairs of capacitors in the list to see which pair is the closest to 36.

Comment: @Kurst maybe you can upload a screen-shot of your Excel data ? it will help us a lot to give you the best answer

Comment: I Guess i figured it out. s2_pos value is turning to 0 by the time it comes out of the While loop. So when you say 'm1.Cells(s2_pos, col).Value' it is like m1.Cells(0, col).Value which doesnt refer any cell in  the sheet

Comment: Why would s2_pos be turning to zero? Does Excel refresh the value of my variables?

Comment: Wait no I think I got it. If I never enter the "If" Statement in the "While" loop then s2_pos is 0. Holy cow thank you so much <3. If I ever bump into on the street, I'll buy you coffee and maybe some donuts :)

Comment: @Kurst I would also change where you place your results. Currently you are running over current values, change the last 2 lines to:  `m1.Cells(s1_pos, col + 1).Value = s2` and `m1.Cells(s2_pos, col + 1).Value = temp_swap`

Comment: @ShaiRado Good idea! I will do that :)

Comment: @Kurst just for my curiosity, you are trying to find the closest pair of capacitors form the entire range? return just 1 result with 2 rows ? or find multiple pairs ?

Comment: No I'm trying to put pairs that have a sum closest to 36 together. And then return a new column of these pairs.

Comment: @Kurst see my answer below, I think you will find it suitable for your needs

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate the issue by setting either `s2_pos` or `col` to 0. In your code this would occur if `candidate < min` was never true, as the result would be that `s2_pos` never gets set.

I would suggest stepping through your code using F8 to understand how you get to this scenario in your data.

As a workaround, place `s2_pos = 0` before `Do While r < 49` and then wrap the last few lines in the below is statement.

```
If s2_pos <> 0 then
    temp_swap = s1
    m1.Cells(s1_pos, col).Value = s2
    m1.Cells(s2_pos, col).Value = temp_swap
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Gary! :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below (which I tested), loops through rows 5 to 48 (like in your code), and finds (per row) the most suitable capacitor (together they have a value closest to 36).
I made some modification to the code, to make it run faster, and I think easier for you to follow.

The screen-shot below shows the results I got on my Demo (**Column C** gets the row number of the capacitor with the best match, **Column D** shows that capacitor value)
[image]

Here is the code :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Experiment()

Dim m1 As Worksheet
Set m1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim col As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Dim Capacitor_Val           As Double
Dim Current_Rng             As Range
Dim Row_Found               As Long
Dim Minimum_Gap             As Double

col = 2

For row = 5 To 47
    ' just a high value to reset this flag
    Minimum_Gap = 3
    For i = row + 1 To 48
        If Abs(36 - (m1.Cells(i, col) + m1.Cells(row, col))) < Minimum_Gap Then
            Minimum_Gap = Abs(36 - (m1.Cells(i, col) + m1.Cells(row, col)))
            Row_Found = i
            Capacitor_Val = m1.Cells(i, col)
        End If
    Next i     

    m1.Cells(row, col + 1).Value = Row_Found
    m1.Cells(row, col + 2).Value = Capacitor_Val

Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: hey Shai, thank you so much for the follow-up. It really helped :)

Comment: @Kurst you welcome, feel free to upvote if it helped you